# Build SQL query with JOIN and limits

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, left-join

Help me please build PostgreSQL query.
There are 2 tables: products(id, title) and prices(id, product_id, price_type, moment, value)

moment - timestamp, can be in past or future

Assume that price_type has only two option: **retail** or **purchase**

But one product may has many retail prices with different moments.

I need select all products with actual retail and purchase prices, where moment less than now.

It's I can done

```
SELECT 
      products.id, 
      products.title_translations AS title,
      retail_prices.moment AS ret_moment,
      pur_prices.value AS purchase,
      retail_prices.value AS retail
FROM products 
LEFT OUTER JOIN prices AS pur_prices ON products.id=pur_prices.product_id AND pur_prices.price_type='purchase' AND pur_prices.moment<current_timestamp
LEFT OUTER JOIN prices AS retail_prices ON products.id=retail_prices.product_id AND retail_prices.price_type='retail' AND retail_prices.moment<current_timestamp
ORDER BY products.id;
```

It works, but returns
product with all prices, but I need only last prices(by moment).

Comment: You mean that wnat the price of the moment more recent?

Comment: so retail and purchase price should be on the same line but could have diffrent "moments" right?

Comment: yes, in result moment has no matter

Answer (score 2):

Just use `ROW_NUMBER` to find what is the last price before current time

```
with last_prices as (
    SELECT 
          products.id, 
          products.title_translations AS title,
          prices.moment,
          prices.value,
          prices.price_type,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY product_id, price_type 
                             ORDER BY moment DESC) as rn
    FROM products 
    LEFT JOIN prices
      ON products.id = prices.product_id 
    WHERE moment < now() 
  )
SELECT id, title, 
       MAX(CASE WHEN price_type = 'retail'
                THEN moment
           END) as retail_moment,
       MAX(CASE WHEN price_type = 'retail'
                THEN value
           END) as retail_price,
       MAX(CASE WHEN price_type = 'purchase'
                THEN moment
           END) as purchase_moment,
       MAX(CASE WHEN price_type = 'purchase'
                THEN value
           END) as purchase_price
FROM last_prices     
WHERE rn = 1
GROUP BY id, title
ORDER BY id
```

Comment: Select still shows `retail_prices.xxxx` and you no longer have that table/alias

Comment: Not disputing that.  but select.... retail_prices.value  will throw a syntax error because you only have products and pur_prices in your joins.  I think you left out a join or something.

Comment: @xQbert fixed. Thanks

Comment: Now I'd be concerned that if purchase and retail have different "moments"... never mind you handled it by partitioning by price type too.... Looks like it should work :P

Answer (score 2):

To keep things organized, and straight in my mind, I'd use CTEs to generate two subsets of price data, one for purchase one for retail and assign a row number in ascending sequence with the lowest number having the most recent moment less than the currenttimestmap.  And then when we join to these ctes, we only return the lowest number assigned.

```
With Pur_prices as (SELECT P.*, row_Number() over (partition by product_ID order by moment desc) RN
                    FROM prices P 
                    WHERE price_Type = 'purchase'
                    and p.moment < current_timestamp)

, Retail_prices as (SELECT P.*, row_Number() over (partition by product_ID order by moment desc) RN
                    FROM prices P 
                    WHERE price_Type = 'retail'
                    and p.moment < current_timestamp)

SELECT 
      p.id, 
      p.title_translations AS title,
      rp.moment AS ret_moment,
      rp.value AS retail,
      pp.moment AS Pur_moment,
      pp.value AS purchase
FROM products p
LEFT JOIN pur_prices pp
  ON p.id=pp.product_id 
 AND pp.RN = 1  --Only show the most recent price less than current time
LEFT JOIN retail_prices rp
  ON p.id=rp.product_id 
 AND RP.RN = 1 --Only show the most recent price less than current time
ORDER BY p.id;
```

The end result should be all products regardless if they have a retail or purchase price; but if they do show the retail/purchase pricing for the most recent moment before now.  My only concern is this implies all pricing has a moment they start (no null values allowed!)

Answer (score 0):

You may be wanting it be ordered with respect to moment in descending order.
Change 
`ORDER BY products.id;`
to 
`ORDER BY  product.id ASC, moment DESC;`

Comment: Little more involved than that since there's a type field involved. and they want retal/purchase on the same row result.